# Nested INotifyPropertyChanged class won't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, nested

got some code what is getting unexpected results:

If i replace the nested class with the Myclass, then there is no problem. What do I miss?
It doesn't matter if I bind text (to an other control) or bind the image.

xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level">
        <Image  Source="{Binding Path=MyClass.ImageSource}" Width="48" Height="48"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="h" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var myClass = new WrappedClass()
                          {
                              MyClass = new MyClass()
                          };

        var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Tiles.png", UriKind.Relative));
        int TileSize = 16;
        var cropRectangle = new Int32Rect((int)0, 0, TileSize, TileSize);
        var croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(image, cropRectangle);


        var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<WrappedClass>();
        observableCollection.Add(myClass);
        observableCollection.Add(myClass);
        observableCollection.Add(myClass);

        h.ItemsSource = observableCollection;
    }

    public class WrappedClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MyClass _myClass;
        public MyClass MyClass
        {
            get
            {
                return _myClass;
            }
            set
            {
                _myClass = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyClass"));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ImageSource _imageSource;
        private string _text = "test";

        public MyClass()
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Tiles.png", UriKind.Relative));
            int TileSize = 16;
            var cropRectangle = new Int32Rect((int)0, 0, TileSize, TileSize);
            _imageSource = new CroppedBitmap(image, cropRectangle);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return _text;
            }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
            }
        }
        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageSource;
            }
            set
            {
                _imageSource = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new    PropertyChangedEventArgs("ImageSource"));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are getting a null reference error, probably wrapped in an invocation error since it is likely happening in your constructor.

Don't do this:

```
PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyClass"));
```

Instead, create a method with a null check:

```
    public void FirePropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And call it like so:

```
FirePropertyChange("MyClass");
```

Comment: Didn't catch the handler == null. Also was there somethign wierd with the DynamicResource, in the application (not the sample)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here

1. Make sure all your classes implement the INotifyPropertyChanged. Especially when dealing with UserControls.
2. I prefer not to hardcode the properties as strings - take a look at my post here on how to do this using reflection.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/using-reflection-with-wpf-and-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface/