# INotifyPropertyChanged does not work from class held in ObservableCollection<Class>

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class, "BaseClass" that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has the following:

BaseClass:

```
    private bool isOn;
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get { return isOn; }
        set
        {
            isOn = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BaseClass:IsOn");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

I then have a class, "DIClass" that also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It also has an `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>`:

DIClass:

```
    public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> ClassesOfA;

    private string iNPCTest;
    public string INPCTest 
    {
        get { return iNPCTest; }
        set
        {
            iNPCTest = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DIClass: INPCTest");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

My ViewModel holds an intance of "DIClass" and registers to it's `PropertyChanged` event. When I set the value of `INPCTest` in "DIClass", the ViewModel 'captures' the event correctly. However when I updated the `IsOn` property within the `ObservableCollection`, as below, the event is not picked up in the ViewModel.

```
ClassesOfA[0].IsOn = true;
```

Why is the INPC interface not working with the nested property?  The question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577332/nested-inotifypropertychanged-class-wont-work) seems quite relevant, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: additional explanation and code:

I can register to the `PropetyChanged` events of the `ObservableCollection`'s items, as such:

```
        ClassesOfA[0].PropertyChanged += DIClass_PropertyChanged;
        ClassesOfA[1].PropertyChanged += DIClass_PropertyChanged;
```

However, this still does not bubble up to notify my `ViewModel`, that a property of my `DIClass`'s `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>` has changed.  I want to use INPC to bubble up event information / property updates up via MVVM layers. But I want to "wrap" them to make my classes cleaner/ less properties lying around

EDIT:

I add this "sketch" of my problem/scenario, with basic naming to make it easy:

[image]

Comment: BaseClass's PropertyChanged Events are not propagated to DIClass. You'd have to register each item in `ClassesOfA` to get notified of their changes. The collection being observable doesn't mean its items' changes are observed, but the collections' (add, remove, ...)

Comment: Hi @Fildor, I should register each item of `ClassesOfA` in  my ViewModel?  something like, `DIClass.ClassesOfA[0].PropertyChanged =+ ...`  ?

Comment: If that's what you need. But I actually doubt it. Why would your ViewModel need to observe this?

Comment: I registered for each item in `DIClass` like this:  `ClassesOfA[0].PropertyChanged += DIClass_PropertyChanged;`, this property changed method is called when `IsOn` is updated.   But I need my ViewModel to know when `IsOn` changes as well, in order to update my UI.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: This is by design.

ObservableCollection has two events:

- CollectionChanged: Fires when the collection changes, e.g. `collection.Add( item )`
- PropertyChanged: Fires when the property changes, e.g. `collection = new ObservablecCollection<T>();`

I think you need no ObservableCollection, because - as far as I understand your question - you want to observe the changes of the properties of the items in the collection. To achieve that you need to register to each observed item's PropertyChanged like this:

```
public List<BaseClass> Collection {get;set;}

public void InitializeCollection( IEnumerable<BaseClass> baseClassCollection){
    Collection = new List<BaseClass>();
    foreach(var item in baseClassCollection){
        item.PropertyChanged += MethodToCallOnPropertyChanges;
        Collection.Add( item );
    }
}

public void MethodToCallOnPropertyChanges(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){
   //react to any property changes
   doSomething();
   //react to specific properties
   if(e != null && e.PropertyName.Equals("isOn"))
       doSomethingOtherStuff();
}
```

This can be very annoying and can causes some other problems.
If I would come across this, I would think about redesigning the ViewModels and the UI. I would try to have an UI which is bound to each BaseClass item. For example, if I have an ListView I would provide an ItemTemplate in which the BaseClass item is bound. Doing so would prevent the need of registering to each item's PropertyChanged.

Comment: thanks, I do bind my UI to an observableCollection. However my question remains - effectively, is there a way to use INPC where you "wrap" a collection of properties.  Thus, I want to be able to use INPC to communicate up layers in MVVM, but I don't want  10+ instances (which hold properties) lying around in my class, which gets clunky. I want to "wrap" them in a collection if possible

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you could create a customized ObservableCollection class that raises a Reset action when a property on a list item changes. It enforces all items to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I made a simple demo and you that you could check:

```
   public class DIClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public ExObservableCollection<BaseClass> ClassesOfA
    ... other code...
     
   }


    public sealed class ExObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ExObservableCollection()
    {
        CollectionChanged += AllObservableCollectionCollectionChanged;
    }

    public ExObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> pItems) : this()
    {
        foreach (var item in pItems)
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void AllObservableCollectionCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, sender, sender, IndexOf((T)sender));
        OnCollectionChanged(args);
    }
}
```

Then you could use the `ExObservableCollection` class in the `DIClass` object. When the properties inside the `BaseClass` changes, the UI will be updated.

**Update:**

Finally, I found out the unexpected behavior you mentioned based on the complex sample. The `ExObservableCollection` class works well and fires the property changed event correctly.

The key point is you think if the property change event in `baseclass` is fired then it will
trigger the property change event in `DIClass` as well, right?  I have to say that is not correct. The property change event only fires in the current class. It won't pass to the parent class unless you handle it in the parent class. It fired only once and notify the UI when the target property is changed.

If I understand your scenario correctly, you want to change the ToggleButton's status when the same property in `BaseClass`object is changed. But the ToggleButtons are bind to `VMData` objects so that you need to get notified when the `BaseClass` objects are changed in the `DIClass` objects. So you want the the property change event of `BaseCasss` triggers the property change event of the `DIClass`.

Handling the property changed event of `BaseClass` in the `DIClass` object is the correct way to do what you want. It's the same like handling `DIClass` event in the ViewModel. But you don't want it since there might be many objects.

Then the first version of your sample is the recommended way to achieve what you want by triggering the property changed event of the `DIClass` on your own.

Comment: Thanks @Roy Li, I implemented your code as is, though it does not work

Comment: I tested the class with the code you post. It works well. Could you please create a blank UWP app? Then add the code you posted in your question and the class I post. Then if you could reproduce the issue, please share the [mcve] with me on Github or OneDrive.

Comment: hi Roy, [here](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExamples.git) is my sample project with all the code being discussed. Appreciate the help

Comment: Tried your sample just now. It's unclear what is the unexpected behavior you mentioned. Do you mean the ToggleButton `one` and `two` does not change when click the `stopall` button?  Again, a minimal sample will be good to find out the issue.

Comment: I am busy creating a minimal console sample.  Yes, when clicking stopall, I expect the `OptionRules_Shell__PropertyChanged` method in the `ViewModel` to "fire"/run, setting the `one` and `two`

Comment: hi Roy, please see a very basic console app [here](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExampleConsoleApp.git)

Comment: When running your sample `DIClass1_PropertyChanged` event did run and I could set the ` VMDataInfoSet[1].IsOn` property correctly. I'll update a screenshot.

Comment: Well, please create a UWP project as the sample instead of a .netcore 3.1 console app.

Comment: The `DIClass1_PropertyChanged` did not fire due to a change of property within the `ObservableCollection`' items. It was due to a setting of another "naked" `property` on the DIClass.

Run that again please and check - I cleaned up and updated the sample project -   also, [this](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExamples.git) is the most basic UWP sample code I can have to duplicate and share

Comment: From the first sample you shared, the DIClass1_PropertyChanged will be fired when clicking the stopall button. I checked the code, the stopall button changes the DIClass of the ObservableCollection.

Comment: That is correct with the first version/ first sample. I have only share one UWP sample, but updated it. [This](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExamples.git) is the only UWP sample I have share - the StopAll button does not feed up to the ViewModel, via ExObservableCollection

Comment: if you look at the last commit, I removed `INPCTest = "INPCTest changed";` within the `StopAll` method, in the DiClass

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check that.

Comment: One last question, for interest maybe, why does it work between the UI (Xaml binding) and the ViewModel?  there is also an "embedded" list of classes in the `ObservableCollection<VMData>`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The `VMData` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as the `BaseClass`. And the ToggleButtons are directly bind to the `VMData` object. So when the property changed event of `VMData` fires, the UI will be update. But there is no UI control binds to `BaseClass` object, so no UI will receive the property changed event that the `BaseClass` object raised. That's why you need to fire the property changed event of `DIClass` on your own.

Comment: The ViewModel is subscribed to propertyChanged events in the DIClass. Just as the XAML is subscribed to propertyChanged events in the ViewModel class. That's what I am comparing

Comment: I'm still confused about what you are trying to figure out. What do you want to ask?

Comment: @Allstar If my solution solves your issue, you could consider making it as the answer

Comment: hi #Roy Li, I added a basic sketch to lay it out again. And in answer: the answers given as well as yours, say to me, that the solution I am looking for is not possible. Therefore I have not allocated an answer yet as a solution

Comment: If I remember it correctly, the first sample you shared could work correctly as you want, right?

Comment: hi Roy Li; no, no example worked as of yet.

Comment: Based on the discussion above, the original sample could trigger the property changed event in the ViewModel which is because you change a property manually in DIClass.

Comment: Yes, a property that was not within a collection<class>

Comment: So, it works, right? You could change the toggle button status by clicking the stopall button.

Comment: No, when code, a non UI thread code changes a property within the, say `ClassA` of `List<ClassA>`, within DIClass. The ViewModel does not pick up the change/event, and the `PropertyChanged()` method is not called

Comment: Do you mean that the sample does not contain your scearnio?

Comment: No it does, always did. Whether it was a UI thread or not, was not relevant - apologies that might have been confusing. I anyway added a non UI thread now to change it. The result and situation remains the same. [updated](https://github.com/derMaaster/GitExamples.git)

Comment: So what you've changed in the sample?

Comment: Yes, twice already. As mentioned on Feb 16th

Comment: So you are using `Task.Run()` to change the property? Propertychanged event needs to be called in the main thread aka UI thread. Please do not change the property on other threads.

Comment: if you followed the logic of the code, you would see that the last step, the actual updating of the property that is binded in XAML, is done by the UI thread, marshalled back to it. Otherwise I would get an error yes.  But this is irrelevant to my question

Comment: It is not recommended to change the data with Task.Run(), if you moved the Task.Run, it could works well.

Comment: it is NOT done by Task.Run()!  But again, irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: Well, after checking your issue, It is still the same problem. You are trying to get a property changed event from `BaseClass` but you did not have a handler for the event. Please check my answer which already explains your issue.